# recorded video using media recorder is corrupted

Tags: android, file, video-capture, mediarecorder

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
```

---

This gets the path of the file and sets eye spy as the name of the folder

```
        String path = String.valueOf(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO));
        File file = new File(path, "Eye Spy");
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        try {
            mCamera.unlock();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        // adjust the camera the way you need
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
```

---

creates a customised camera profile

```
        CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        profile.fileFormat = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
        profile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP;
        profile.videoFrameHeight = 240;
        profile.videoFrameWidth = 320;
        profile.videoBitRate = 15;
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getSurface());
```

---

this line gets the path of the file and sets it as output

```
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getPath());

        //set max size
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

creates a thumbnail for the created folder, which is eye spy

```
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can someone help us since my partner and I don't know what to do anymore...... the folder can successfully be created but the video is always corrupted. We have attempted different ways but none of them worked

Comment: Did you ever get it working? It looks like there might be some issues with the profile. What size is the corrupted file? I am running into and issue where the file is corrupted and the size is always 24b.